# JavaFX FlowPane Wrap Text

Tags: javafx, word-wrap

I'm creating a custom flowpane for an output console in a gui.  I've been studying the code found [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Layout/Flow%20Pane) just trying to get the setPrefWrapLength to work.  By default it's set to 200 here, but adding more text to one of the labels does not show it wrapping.

So, I guess my question is, how do I get a FlowPane to wrap properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The FlowPane width is defined by the Pane it lives in.  Although my Pane had a width of less than 550, I had to set it's max width to 550 as well:  pane.setMaxWidth(550)